# How to get what was typed in an inputText and insert without firebase with React-Native?

Tags: react-native

How to get what was typed in an inputText and insert without firebase with React-Native?

Comment: Best to reask in English as best you can.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not in English - this is an **English-only** site - please respect the rules of the site!

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve what was types into a text input you can use :

```
onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
```

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#onchangetext

I'm not sure what you meant by "without firebase", I'm guessing this is a translation issue.